# An Alternative Vector (Copy Assignment Operator)

Tags: c++, vectors

This is a continuation of [An Alternative Vector](/q/121127), taking a closer look at the copy assignment operator.

In the following code, I am only posting the new version of the copy assignment operator; all the rest of the code is unchanged.

```
namespace ThorsAnvil
{
    // Traits classes
    //      SimpleCopyableAssignableTraitNoThrow: 
    //      SimpleDestructableTrivialy 
    // Helper classes
    //      SimpleDestructableTrivialy
    //      SimpleCopy

    // Forward declare the vector
    template<typename T>
    class Vector;
```

Declarations:

```
    template<typename T>
    struct SimpleCopyableAssignableTraitNoThrow
    {
        static constexpr bool value = std::is_nothrow_destructible<T>::value
                                &&    std::is_nothrow_copy_assignable<T>::value;
    };
    template<typename T>
    struct SimpleDestructableTrivialy
    {
        static constexpr bool value = std::is_trivially_destructible<T>::value;
    };
    template<typename T, bool = SimpleCopyableAssignableTraitNoThrow<T>::value>
    class SimpleCopy
    {
        public:
            void simpleCopy(Vector<T>& dst, Vector<T> const& src) const;
    };
    template<typename T, bool = SimpleDestructableTrivialy<T>::value>
    class SimpleDestroy
    {
        public:
            void destroyElements(Vector<T>& obj);
    };
```

Updated Vector

```
    template<typename T>
    class Vector
    {
        // The rest (see original question for details).

        friend class SimpleCopy<T>;
        friend class SimpleDestroy<T>;
        public:
            Vector& operator=(Vector const& value) noexcept(SimpleCopyableAssignableTraitNoThrow<T>::value)
            {
                SimpleCopy<T>   copier;
                copier.simpleCopy(*this, value);
                return *this;
            }
    };
```

SimpleDestroy

```
    template<typename T>
    class SimpleDestroy<T, true>
    {
        public:
            // The elements in object are trivially destructible.
            // This means nothing is done. As an optimization we
            // don't need to do anything to the elements, just
            // reset the size
            void destroyElements(Vector<T>& obj)
            {
                obj.length  = 0;
            }
    };
    template<typename T>
    class SimpleDestroy<T, false>
    {
        public:
            // destructor is non trivial but does not throw
            void destroyElements(Vector<T>& obj)
            {
                for(int loop = 0; loop < obj.length; ++loop)
                {
                    obj.buffer[obj.length - 1 - loop].~T();
                }
                obj.length = 0;
            }
    };
```

SimpleCopy

```
    template<typename T>
    class SimpleCopy<T, true>
    {
        public:
            // Neither constructor or destructor throw.
            // So we can optimize the copy.
            void simpleCopy(Vector<T>& dst, Vector<T> const& src) const
            {
                if (&dst == &src)
                {
                    return;
                }

                // Destroy the members of the current object
                SimpleDestroy<T>    destroyer;
                destroyer.destroyElements(dst);

                // Copy from the source object to the detonation
                // thus reusing the memory underneath. It only tries
                // to reallocate if the current object needs to be
                // re-sized.
                for(auto const& value: src)
                {
                    dst.push(value);
                }
            }
    };
    template<typename T>
    class SimpleCopy<T, false>
    {
        public:
            // Constructor or Destructor may fail.
            // So use Copy & Swap idiom to handle resource
            // allocation correctly.
            void simpleCopy(Vector<T>& dst, Vector<T> const& src) const
            {
                Vector<T>     tmp(src);       // Copy
                tmp.swap(dst);                // Swap
            }
    };           

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Although there's a comment in `SimpleDestroy<T, false>::destroyElements()` claiming that `~T()` doesn't throw, there's very little to assure that.  Our only guarantee is that we currently call it only from the version of `SimpleCopy` that handles non-throwing destructors, but it would be easy to accidentally break that requirement - for example, we might want to use it to implement `~Vector<T>()`.

It's easy to make it more robust - decrement `obj.length` as we go along, rather than once at the end.  That makes the behaviour more like standard containers.

---

I don't see why `destroyElements()` and `simpleCopy()` need their own (publicly-visible!) classes.  Those classes could be private member classes of `Vector`, but I think that's still overkill: the functions may be better as private members of the `Vector` class:

```
private:
    void destroyElements_trivial();
    void destroyElements_nontrivial();
    void destroyElements() {
        (std::is_trivially_destructible_v<T>
            ? destroyElements_trivial : destroyElements_nontrivial)();
    }

    void simpleCopy_trivial(Vector<T> const& src);
    void simpleCopy_nontrivial(Vector<T> const& src);
    void simpleCopy(Vector<T> const& src) {
        (SimpleCopyableAssignableTraitNoThrow<T>::value
            ? simpleCopy_trivial : simpleCopy_nontrivial)(src);
    }
```

Implementation is straightforward:

```
template<typename T>
void Vector<T>::destroyElements_trivial()
{
    length  = 0;
}

template<typename T>
void Vector<T>::destroyElements_nontrivial()
{
    while (length) {
        buffer[--length].~T();
    }
    length = 0;
}


template<typename T>
void Vector<T>::simpleCopy_trivial(Vector<T> const& src)
{
    if (this == &src) {
        return;
    }

    // Destroy the members of the current object
    destroyElements();

    // Copy from the source object
    for (auto const& value: src) {
        push(value);
    }
}
template<typename T>
void Vector<T>::simpleCopy_nontrivial(Vector<T> const& src)
{
    Vector<T> tmp(src);       // Copy
    swap(tmp);                // Swap
}
```

We can further simplify into single methods, using `if constexpr`:

```
private:
    void destroyElements();
    void simpleCopy(Vector<T> const& src);
```

```
template<typename T>
void Vector<T>::destroyElements()
{
    if constexpr (!std::is_trivially_destructible_v<T>) {
        while (length) {
            buffer[--length].~T();
        }
    }
    length  = 0;
}


template<typename T>
void Vector<T>::simpleCopy(Vector<T> const& src)
{
    if (this == &src) {
        return;
    }

    if constexpr (SimpleCopyableAssignableTraitNoThrow<T>::value) {
        // Destroy the members of the current object
        destroyElements();

        // Copy from the source object
        for (auto const& value: src) {
            push(value);
        }
    } else {
        Vector<T> tmp(src);       // Copy
        swap(tmp);                // Swap
    }
}
```

That's cleaner and shorter than having the destruct and copy outsourced to friend classes.  It also enables us to dispense with the traits classes (which can move to being `static constexpr` members), and yields this much reduced version of the question code:

```
#include <type_traits>

namespace ThorsAnvil
{
    template<typename T>
    class Vector
    {
        // copied from original question so it compiles
        std::size_t     capacity;
        std::size_t     length;
        T*              buffer;

        static constexpr bool is_nothrow_assignable =
            std::is_nothrow_destructible_v<T> && std::is_nothrow_copy_assignable_v<T>;
        static constexpr bool is_trivially_destructible =
            std::is_trivially_destructible_v<T>;

        public:
            Vector& operator=(Vector const& value) noexcept(is_nothrow_assignable)
            {
                simpleCopy(value);
                return *this;
            }

        T* begin() const;
        T* end() const;
        void push(T const& u);

    private:
        void destroyElements();
        void simpleCopy(Vector<T> const& src) noexcept(is_nothrow_assignable);
    };


    template<typename T>
    void Vector<T>::destroyElements()
    {
        if constexpr (is_trivially_destructible) {
            length = 0;
        } else {
            while (length) {
                buffer[--length].~T();
            }
        }
    }



    template<typename T>
    void Vector<T>::simpleCopy(Vector<T> const& src) noexcept(is_nothrow_assignable)
    {
        if (this == &src) {
            return;
        }

        if constexpr (is_nothrow_assignable) {
            // Destroy the members of the current object
            destroyElements();

            // Copy from the source object
            for (auto const& value: src) {
                push(value);
            }
        } else {
            Vector<T> tmp(src);       // Copy
            swap(tmp);                // Swap
        }
    }

}
```

---

Simple typos (more important than usual, given that this is didactic code):

- Trivialy -> **Trivially**
- detonation -> **destination**